# a std_msgs/ColorRGBA message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone

i am just a beginner with ROS system. i am trying to writing a publisher node, which send a colorRGBA message to the subscriber about the topic "visualization_kit".

but it's unable to display the color,here are my codes

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::ColorRGBA>("chatter", 1000);

  while(ros::ok())
  {
    std_msgs::ColorRGBA color;

    color.r = 255;
    color.g = 0;
    color.b = 0;
    color.a = 1;
 
    //draw.colors.push_back(color)

    ROS_INFO("%s","visualisation_kit");

    chatter_pub.publish(color);

    ros::spinOnce();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53527/a-std_msgs/colorrgba-message/) by [anycast](https://answers.ros.org/users/4071/anycast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your code, you are advertising the messages on the topic "chatter". From your description, it appears you want to publish on the topic "visualisation_kit":

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::ColorRGBA>("visualisation_kit", 1000);
```

A good tool to debug the input and output topics of your nodes is [rosnode](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosnode). In your case, for example, type this in a console window after executing your "talker" node:

```
rosnode info talker
```

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1